# type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'DateTime?'

Tags: flutter, dart

I get the following error when adding the date information returned from the item to the "tarih", "vadeTarihi" fields whose type is DateTime

type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'DateTime?'

```html
    masterDetailTemp = masterDetailTemp.copyWith(
        master: masterDetailTemp.master!.copyWith(  
          // the line where i got the error
          tarih: item.tarih,
          vadeTarihi: item.vadeTarihi,
        ));
```

Type of values returned from item:

Comment: give us The code to work on it

Comment: have you tried DateTime.parse();?

Comment: You need to parse  dateTime to String

Comment: i tried it didn't work @ShailandraRajput

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this worked:

```
tarih: DateTime.tryParse(item.tarih.toString()),
vadeTarihi: DateTime.tryParse(item.vadeTarihi.toString()),
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `SatisFaturaMaster` model class. Check the type of `kayitTarihi` and `tarih` variables if they are Strings then you need to parse the DateTime to convert it to a String.
To do that;

```
kayitTarihi.toString(); tarih.toString();
```

If you want to store `tarih` and `vadeTarihi` as DateTime do the following.

```
 masterDetailTemp = masterDetailTemp.copyWith(
    master: masterDetailTemp.master!.copyWith(  
      // the line where i got the error
      tarih: DateTime.tryParse(item.tarih),
      vadeTarihi: DateTime.tryParse(item.vadeTarihi),
    ));
```

Comment: sorry that didn't work either

Comment: I updated the post to show the exact places to change. Can you try the second method if the types of tarih and vadeTarihi are DateTime? @GülsenKeskin

Comment: I've tried this many times before, unfortunately it didn't work. :(

Comment: If vadeTarihi and tarih is not nullable. Instead of 'tryParse' use 'parse' as the following, DateTime.parse(tarih) and DateTime.parse(vadeTarihi). I hope this will solve your problem. If it didn't then please share the type of tarih and vadeTarih in your model class and in your calling method.